# Send information from PHP to Java

Tags: java, php, android

I want to send some information from PHP to Java. Why? Because I have a database on my server, and I get information from my database using PHP scripts.

Now I want to send that information to my client in Java. How can I do that?

I send information from Java to PHP by POST, and it works well, but I don't know how can I do the reverse.

Can you help me?

I saw this code, from a GET connection in Java... is it correct?

```
public String HttpClientTutorial(){
    String url = "http://testes.neoscopio.com/myrepo/send.php";
       InputStream content = null;  
       try {  
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url)); 

         content = response.getEntity().getContent();  
       } catch (Exception e) {  
         Log.e("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);  
       }  


  String response = content.toString();

  return response;
}
```

P.S: I'm an android developer, not a Java developer...

Comment: what do u mean by android developer ??

Comment: So are you saying that you want the Java part to act as a server that the PHP connects to, or do you mean you want to respond to that POST call that the Java client sends to you PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [exampledepot: Sending POST request](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html) (Modified to get the output of your `send.php`.)

```
try {
    // Construct data
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
    data += "&amp;" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://testes.neoscopio.com/myrepo/send.php");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process line...
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

P.S. This should work fine on Android. :)

(I usually `import static java.net.URLEncoder.encode` but that's a matter of taste.)

Comment: The code at exampledepot obviously didn't use `testes.neoscopio.com`, that's what I changed :-)

Comment: of course.. but in file send.php How do I send the information to the java? this code will get something to the php right?

Comment: i have 1 more question.. it's possible send information by the 'GET' connection ? like.. a send a string to send.php.. and receive the same output..

Comment: Sure. Change the URL to `send.php?yourVariable=aValue`